# Right place to offer or send Channel in MVI pattern

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I load data in recycleView in advance. In order to do that I have following code in onCreate() of Activity :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setupUI()
        setupViewModel()
        observeViewModel()
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mainViewModel.userIntent.offer(MainIntent.FetchUser)
        }
    }
```

As you see I `offer()` when savedInstanceState is null, The problem is when we have process death ( you can simply create it by activating Do not keep activities in developer option), reload of data will not be triggered.

another option is to use it inside `init` block of ViewModel, but problem is I want to have bellow unit test which I can verify all three states :

```
    @Test
    fun givenServerResponse200_whenFetch_shouldReturnSuccess() {
        runBlockingTest {
            `when`(apiService.getUsers()).thenReturn(emptyList())
            val apiHelper = ApiHelperImpl(apiService)
            val repository = MainRepository(apiHelper)
            val viewModel = MainViewModel(repository)
            viewModel.state.asLiveData().observeForever(observer)
            viewModel.userIntent.send(MainIntent.FetchUser)
        }
        verify(observer, times(3)).onChanged(captor.capture())
        verify(observer).onChanged(MainState.Idle)
        verify(observer).onChanged(MainState.Loading)
        verify(observer).onChanged(MainState.Users(emptyList()))
    }
```

If I use the init block option as soon as ViewModel initialized, `send` or `offer` will be called while `observeForever` did not be used for LiveData in the above unit test.

Here is my ViewModel class :

```
class MainViewModel(
    private val repository: MainRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val userIntent = Channel<MainIntent>(Channel.UNLIMITED)
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<MainState>(MainState.Idle)
    val state: StateFlow<MainState>
        get() = _state

    init {
        handleIntent()
    }

    private fun handleIntent() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userIntent.consumeAsFlow().collect {
                when (it) {
                    is MainIntent.FetchUser -> fetchUser()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun fetchUser() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.value = MainState.Loading
            _state.value = try {
                MainState.Users(repository.getUsers())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                MainState.Error(e.localizedMessage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the solution for the above scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I found is moving `fetchUser` method and another `_state` as MutableStateFlow to Repository layer and `observeForever` it in Repository for local unit test, as a result I can send or offer `userIntent` in init block off ViewModel.

I will have following `_state` in ViewModel :

```
val userIntent = Channel<MainIntent>(Channel.UNLIMITED)
    private val _state = repository.state
    val state: StateFlow<MainState>
        get() = _state
```