# How to unit test SharedFlow on Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have an android viewmodel class with the following property

```
private val _trainingNavigationEvents = MutableSharedFlow<NavigationEventTraining>(replay = 0)
    val trainingNavigationEvents = _trainingNavigationEvents.asSharedFlow()

fun navigate(navigationEvent: NavigationEventTraining) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _trainingNavigationEvents.emit(navigationEvent)
        }
    }
```

I am using a SharedFlow as it solves the SingleLiveEvent problem.

The issue arises when I try and unit test the code. I can't see how to use turbine (or supplied primitives) to get it to work.

```
    @ExperimentalTime
    @Test
    fun `navigate`() = runBlockingTest {
        viewModel.handleIntent(TrainingViewModel.TrainingIntent.ShowQuestions)

        viewModel.navigationEvents.test {
            assertEquals(
                TrainingViewModel.TrainingNavigationEvent.NavigateToQuestions::class,
                expectItem()::class
            )
            cancelAndConsumeRemainingEvents()
        }
    }
```

and I get

```
kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCancellationException: Timed out waiting for 1000 ms
```

I know that a SharedFlow never completes and that may be part of the reason but I have been unable to find any examples of how to do this instead.

I am using Junit 5 and am using a TestCoroutineDispatcher class extension.

Comment: This is how I test hot flows without any library.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68909180/2719243

Answer (score 6):

In the Turbine's documentation there is a [Hot Flows](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine#hot-flows) section, I think we could do something like this:

```
@ExperimentalTime
@Test
fun `navigate`() = runBlockingTest {
    viewModel.navigationEvents.test {
        viewModel.handleIntent(TrainingViewModel.TrainingIntent.ShowQuestions)
        assertEquals(
            TrainingViewModel.TrainingNavigationEvent.NavigateToQuestions::class,
            expectItem()::class
        )
        cancelAndConsumeRemainingEvents()
    }
}
```

pretty much moving the trigger inside of the Turbine's `.test {` block

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849507/what-is-the-better-way-to-use-turbine-to-test-coroutine-stateflow), but my question is how to improve the Stateflow test.

I think the issue is that you need to call the ViewModel initialization in the test.

ex:

```
 @ExperimentalTime
    @Test
    fun `navigate`() = runBlockingTest {
        viewModel = ViewModel(...)
        viewModel.handleIntent(TrainingViewModel.TrainingIntent.ShowQuestions)

        viewModel.navigationEvents.test {
            assertEquals(
                TrainingViewModel.TrainingNavigationEvent.NavigateToQuestions::class,
                expectItem()::class
            )
            cancelAndConsumeRemainingEvents()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found it useful to wrap the ViewModel under test in a @Before annotated function:

using lateinit:```
  private lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel

  @Before
  fun createViewModelUnderTest() {
    viewModel = ViewModel( ... )
  }
```