# What is the better way to use turbine to test coroutine StateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

I am looking for a better way to test coroutine. Currently, I'm using [Turbine](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine) as the test helper. However, I have some difficulty improving the timeout issue.

ex:

```
class RepositoryTest {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var sut: SubjectToTest

    private val testDispatchers = TestDispatchersProvider.dispatchers

    private val mockAddressRepository = mockk<AddressRepository>(relaxed = true)
    private val mockApiService = mockk<ApiService>(relaxed = true)
    private val mockCardsRepository = mockk<CardsRepository>(relaxed = true)

    @Before
    fun setup() {

         sut = SutRepository(
            apiService = mockApiService,
            dispatchersProvider = testDispatchers,
            restCallHandler = testRestCallHandler,
            addressRepo = mockAddressRepository,
            cardRepo = mockCardsRepository,
        )
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        unmockkAll()
    }

    private val mockCardResponse = CardResponse(
        data = DataModel(
            listOf(
                ...
            )
        )
    )


    @Test
    fun `fetchData has success response then return Data`() = runBlockingTest {
        // Given
        coEvery {
            mockAddressService.fetchAddresss(any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any())
        } returns Response.success(mockCardResponse)
        every {
            mockCardsRepository.fetchCard
        } returns mockFlow()

        testRestCallHandler.callResult = ...

        // Test
        sut.fetchMessages(true)
        sut.StateFlow.test {
            expectItem().assertObject{ ... }
            expectItem().assertSize(1)
        }

    }
}
```

the code above, has **TimeoutCancellationException**.

```
kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCancellationException: Timed out waiting for 1000 ms

    at |b|b|b(Coroutine boundary.|b(|b)
```

by solving the above issue, I move the class initialization in the test.

```
    @Test
    fun `fetchData has success response then return Data`() = runBlockingTest {
        // Given
        coEvery {
            mockAddressService.fetchAddresss(any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any())
        } returns Response.success(mockCardResponse)
        every {
            mockCardsRepository.fetchCard
        } returns mockFlow()

        testRestCallHandler.callResult = ...

        // Test
        sut = SutRepository(
            apiService = mockApiService,
            dispatchersProvider = testDispatchers,
            restCallHandler = testRestCallHandler,
            addressRepo = mockAddressRepository,
            cardRepo = mockCardsRepository,
        )
        sut.fetchMessages(true)
        sut.StateFlow.test {
            expectItem().assertType<List<DataMode>> {
                this.assertListSize(1)
            }
            cancel()
        }
    }
```

after moving the initialization in the test, the test pass but I am looking for a way to improve it.