# Testing intermediate emissions for a coroutines Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I updated Kotlin coroutines to v1.6.0 and while addressing the changes in the tests I stumbled upon an issue when trying to test intermediate emissions. There's a [section in the migration guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/MIGRATION.md#testcoroutinedispatcher-for-testing-intermediate-emissions) describing how to go about writing this kind of test, but the proposed solution is not fully working and I'd like to understand where's my mistake.

In particular, I have a `StateFlow` that gets updated twice in a coroutine launched in the `viewModelScope` (which internally uses `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`). However, when testing, the intermediate emission is not collected.

Simplified example:

```kotlin
class VM : ViewModel() {
    val stateFlow = MutableStateFlow("a")

    fun foo() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            stateFlow.value = "b"
            // [...] call to a suspend fun
            stateFlow.value = "c"
        }
    }
}

class AbcTest {
    @Test
    fun testFlow() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(UnconfinedTestDispatcher())
        runTest {
            val vm = VM()
            val values = mutableListOf<String>()
            val job = launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler)) {
                vm.stateFlow.collect(values::add)
            }
            vm.foo()
            job.cancel()

            assertEquals(listOf("a", "b", "c"), values)
        }
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

This test fails with: `expected: <[a, b, c]> but was: <[a, c]>`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to add some delay when using suspend function in VM, like this https://github.com/Kotlin-Android-Open-Source/MVI-Coroutines-Flow/blob/8ededadebed0eb46fc46f427cbcf8ef36d650b4b/mvi/mvi-testing/src/main/java/com/hoc/flowmvi/mvi_testing/BaseMviViewModelTest.kt#L46

Comment: Hey, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72854091/5040556